# Help with scond derivative test $\cos x-x$ interval $[0, 4\pi]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I am confused on how the interval can go to four pi, because when you find the critical numbers, you get $\frac\pi2, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{2},$ and $\frac{7\pi}{2}$.

However, the last two aren't on the unit circle, so when you plug them into the second derivative, you get $-\cos\left(\frac{7pi}{2}\right)$, which I don't know how to find.

Answer (score 0):

The $\cos$ function is defined for all values of $x\in\mathbb R$ (in fact, for all values of $\mathbb C$. If $x\notin [0,2\pi]$, simply use the fact that $\cos$ is periodic, i.e.

$$\cos(2\pi + x) = \cos (x)$$
For $\frac{7\pi}2$, this means that $$\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{2}\right) = \cos\left(2\pi + \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: To me it just seems like you took out the 2pi. Is that what you did or am I missing a step?

Comment: @user3261963 I used the fact that $\cos(2\pi + x) = \cos(x)$.